# Return from AJAX -- Not understaing

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, return

I'm playing with AJAX and PHP.

**Description:**

I have a HTML page that has some vanilla JS and AJAX.

My AJAX object makes a request to a PHP server. The server returns some JSON object. Which my code takes and processes (creates a Table dynamically and with the data).

**What I'm looking for:**

However, I would like to have the data (JSON object) stored in global *VAR* that any function in my JS script can access.

I don't want to do all the processing within the AJAX resquest.

**What I've read:**

I have read the aspects of asynchronous and synchronous requests, but I'm still confused on how to retrieve the data with the callback functions.Because every time I try to return the data I keep getting a *undefine* value.

If guys are able to help me return and understand how this part of JS works it would be awesome.

**Attached please find my code and an image** of what I'm doing (please take into account that the image shows a working system but all the processing is happening inside the AJAX request which is what I to change).

Thank you.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Professor Page - Group 5</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link type="text/css" href="SORUCE FILE" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- JS
  <script src="prof_create_xm_page.js"> </script>
  -->


</head>
<body onload="get_questions()">
  <section>
    <!-- SIDE MENUE -->
    <nav>
      <ul id="main_manu">
       <li> <a href="SORUCE FILE">Home</a></li>
       <li>Exams
    <ul>
       <li> <a href="SORUCE FILE"> Add Questions</a> </li>
       <li> <a href="SORUCE FILE">Create Exam</a> </li>
    </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Students
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="SORUCE FILE">Grading</a></li>
    </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
     <div id="outter_container">
      <div id="display_ques" class="innter_pannel">
      </div>
      <div id="selected_ques" class="innter_pannel">
      </div>
      <div>
       <button id="create_exam" onclick="create_exam()">Create Exam</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </article>
  </section>

  <script>
   /*--------------------------------------------*/
   function contact_server(data){
    //Create AJAX object
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var method = "POST";
    var url = "URL TO CONTACT";

    //Open Connection
    xobj.open(method,url,true);
    xobj.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xobj.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
     if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == 200){
      var respuesta_ = JSON.parse(xobj.responseText);
      console.log("AJAX");
      return respuesta_;
     }
    };

    xobj.send(data);
   }

   /*--------------------------------------------*/
   function display_questions(data){
    //SOME ACTION
   }
   /*--------------------------------------------*/
   function get_questions(){
    var data={
     "user":"ucid",
     "case":"GetQuestions",
     "filter":7
    };

    data= JSON.stringify(data);

    var response = contact_server(data);

    display_questions(response);

   }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: That simply isn't possible. You can store the data in that global variable all you want, but you won't be able to access that data until after it has been retrieved. The only way to cause your code to "wait" for said data to be retrieved is to use a callback, such as the one all of your logic is in.

Comment: @KevinB how can I write such callback function, that's where my problem is. I do not know how to implement it. Posts I've read have not been that helpful.

Comment: The same way you wrote `xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {...}`, only without the `return` line. You can call another function at that point, but you *cannot* return a value.

Comment: @KevinB, you mean that if I write something like var results = function(){ do something } ... then inside the xobj.onreadystatechange = function () { ... results(data); ... } It would work?

Comment: Yes, that would work

Comment: @KevinB, ok I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: @KevinB, I was not able to get to work. :(